# After moving root partition in Linux Lite (Lubuntu), do I need to run fsck?

Tags: fsck, lubuntu, move-partition

I finally migrated from Windows to Linux, and I chose Linux Lite (based on Lubuntu) as my first attempt, through dual-booting my PC. I loved using Linux, so I decided to steal most of the space of my Windows partition and give it to my ext4 partition using gparted Live Disk.

The problem is that I couldn't simply expand the partition, I needed to move it first (to the left) and *then* expand it to all the unallocated space. gparted does not recommend it and mentions I might not be able to boot after moving the root partition.

My boot partition is still the Windows partition. So I tried to restart the computer normally and everything went fine, I booted to the Linux partition.

But I thought the system was a little slower than usual and for the first time it froze (I could move my mouse, but all else was unresponsive). I waited for an hour but it stayed the same. So I turned off the power to the computer.

My question is: I thought the only problem I had when resizing was booting, but is it necessary to do `fsck` or a similar procedure to verify the integrity or fix errors? Also, should I run `update-grub`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It will not hurt to run `fsck`, but probably not needed. Did it work the 2nd, 3rd time you booted?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I got afraid and thought it was best to ask before powering it up again. Do you suggest any arguments to `fsck`? Nice name, by the way:)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I just powered on the computer. Everything seems to be fine (I forgot to mention, but last time, the opening sound for starting the system got a hick-up (just a part of the sound, pause, then the rest). Now it sounded complete. I'll report any other changes

Comment: Yes I would do the `fsck` it will only cost you time. If you have any of your own files in the partition, then also back them up (you should always do this any way). If necessary reinstall (should only take 30 minutes). It is best to use one partition for the OS and another for `/home`.  And then use etckeeper for `/etc` (it is a pain to loose OS config).

Comment: Glade to read that it is working. Hope it stays that way. Remember with backups, separate `/home`,  and a fast install, there is no fear.

Comment: Thank you! So far, so good, no more problems and it went back to being snappy. I think it was only a coincidence, I'll heed your advice and leave `fsck` for another occasion